# Laravel Scout dynamically limit which keys are searched/returned

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I'm setting up Laravel Scout for searching (experimenting with Meilisearch as the driver), however, I want to limit what fields are used for search (and ideally which fields are returned) based on a users permissions.

As an example, a `User` model might have the following fields:

```
id: 5,
name: John,
email: john.doe@hotmail.com,
phone: 0412345678
```

I'd like everyone to be able to search by `name` and `email`, however I want to limit searching by `phone number` to only authorised users (eg. admins)

I've not been able to find any ways to limit what fields are searched/returned dynamically. I've only been able to find ways to limit what is initially sent to the index.

(on a slight tangent, is it possible to get the weighting of the search returned as well?)